# Why SeekableByteChannel.read() always return -1 in linux?

Tags: java, linux

In linux, I want to read the delta  when some lines are added to the target file with SeekableByteChannel.
Just like the following:

1, Run the code,

2, Add some line the target file, and then I discover that "seekableByteChannel.size() == size" be always true.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException {
        Path path = Paths.get( "/root/desktop/file1" );
        long size = path.toFile().length();
        // read a file using SeekableByteChannel
        try (SeekableByteChannel seekableByteChannel = Files
            .newByteChannel( path, EnumSet.of( StandardOpenOption.READ ) )) {
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 1 );
            String encoding = System.getProperty( "file.encoding" );
            buffer.clear();
            seekableByteChannel.position(size);
            while(seekableByteChannel.size() == size) {
                Thread.sleep( 1000 );
            }            
            while ( seekableByteChannel.read( buffer ) > 0 ) {
                buffer.flip();
                System.out.print( Charset.forName( encoding ).decode( buffer ) );
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
        catch ( IOException ex ) {
            System.err.println( ex );
        }
    }
}
```

But windows does not have this problem

My jdk version: 1.7.0._45

Because I install all the machine on VMFS5, after I change to install them on NFS, the problems go.
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Uhm, why `path.toFile().length()`? Use the Java 7 API for that as well: `Files.readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class).size()`

Comment: Also, you can use a `WatchService`

Comment: I just use path.toFile().length() to get the original length of file. I mainly  want to know why seekableByteChannel can't load the added lines that I add to the file, and then I am able to seekableByteChannel  to read the delta.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but as to using the new API, use it fully ;)

Comment: Well, I have posted a solution not so long ago that does just that by using a `WatchService`. I'll need to find it again but it does what you want.

Comment: You don't need it. Just sleep while the following `read()` method returns -1.

Comment: @EJP using a `WatchKey` is actually more efficient when the implementation doesn't poll the filesystem

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that the read() always return -1 in linux

Comment: @Alex found the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485267/java-randomaccessfile-java-under-linux-not-working-correctly/22487705#22487705

Comment: @fge - That's only part of the answer.  We still don't know why the value returned by the channel doesn't change.

Comment: @StephenC yeah and that is strange, since the code in the answer I linked to does rely on the channel size. I don't believe that my environment has anything special (Linux, btrfs filesystem), so we'll have to wait and see what the OP makes out of the code I have linked to...

Comment: @fge I have tested your link in my ubuntu, the code can't grab a key when I add a line to the target file, so the problem still exists.But it works well on windows

Comment: @Alex that is most strange... What filesystem are you using and what version of Ubuntu is that? Also, have you tried with an `AsynchronousByteChannel`?

Comment: I have a suspicion that this might be an issue with the file system implementation; i.e. outside of Java.  Certainly, some exotic file system types behave a bit strangely.  What FS are you using @Alex?

Comment: Ubuntu version: 12.04.3 LTS, for me, redhat and solaris aslo have this problem.

Comment: @Stephen C My Ubuntu's FS info: /dev/sdf1    ext4.