# Spying on a Path in Mockito

Tags: java, mockito, nio

I'm trying to ***spy*** on a ***Path*** using ***Mockito***

```
dirSpy = spy(Files.createTempDirectory(DIR_NAME));
```

and I get an error saying

> Mockito cannot mock this class: class sun.nio.fs.UnixPath
>   Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes.
>   If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.

[I can post a longer stack trace if you think it is needed]

I assume that this is because the Path has a native implementation - my question is if there is some workaround that will enable me to check if a specific location was accessed during a test

**what I'm trying to test-**
I have a directories structure for each user - I wanted to do a test that checks that in the case that there are no users, there isn't a redundant work done and that the root of all users isn't accessed.

In my over whole test logic this is a minor verification and i can do without it - just thought it's something that is nice to have

Comment: In this case, it is because `UnixPath` is package-private in `sun.nio.fs`. It is not `final` though. See [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/UnixPath.java).

Comment: Have you tried PowerMockito?

Comment: @Ray - Thanks. I didn't use PowerMockito until now and i'm not sure this specific test verification I was looking into justifies the work needed for this (I mean that in my dev env it can take some work given the specific dependencies management method we have)

Comment: All the sun.xx classes are private to the Java implementation and off limits of Mockito. There are ways to get direct access to these classes but it is really not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

> my question is if there is some workaround that will enable me to check if a specific location was accessed during a test

Yes, using a [`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).

Note that should you be able to do it, watching the path itself won't bring you much: operations on `Path`s don't do I/O except for `.toRealPath()` *if* called at all and *if* the filesystem has symlinks support (OK, you use some Unix variant, so that is likely to be the case). The real I/O is done by the path's [`FileSystemProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html). But you won't be able to spy that either...

A `WatchService` is therefore your best solution.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485267/java-randomaccessfile-java-under-linux-not-working-correctly/22487705#22487705) for an example. And please note that a `WatchService` is filesystem dependent; this means you are *still* better off doing file I/O from a class of yours which you *can* spy ;)

Comment: I want to be able to verify if something like _resolve_ was called - the _WatchService_ lets me identify CUD actions - not a _read_ action

Comment: @NoaDrach But `.resolve()` will not read anything! It is just an operation producing a new path, without any access; you can resolve to non existing paths. What if you started from the beginning and told us _what_ you wanted to spy?

Comment: Well then, why don't you just compare the access time of the directory before and after? Or is your fs mounted with noatime as well? Don't forget that you can get a LOT of attributes from the file (see [here](http://andreinc.net/2013/12/05/java-7-nio-2-tutorial-file-attributes/))

Comment: This was a good direction but - i check the last access time on dir **A** before and after the actual code execution and it doesn't change. I thinks it's because when i do have users i create the following structure in my test setup **A/User/Uploads** and then in the tested code doing `A.resolve("User/Uploads")` doesn't effect the  access time on **A**.  I guess there is no real justification in my test to dig dipper.  But thank you for all the points you raised - I think I learned some new things

Comment: Welcome ! But you know, you _can_ spot creations with `WatchService`

Comment: Hey, wait, you _do_ have another way; can you change your test path for your setup? (note that you can also bulk collect file metadata using a `FileVisitor`)

Comment: Yes I create the test root using the command i specified in the original post and than i feed it to the tested class

Comment: OK well, my idea was long lived I'm afraid; Google has jimfs, an in-memory filesystem, but its classes are final as well.